# Hibernate @MappedSuperClass with ElementCollection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm refactoring my application which uses Hibernate (with Spring). I have a couple of entities which has items associated in an ElementCollection. So before it looked like:

```
@Entity
class GroupA {
    .... id, .. omitted
    @ElementCollection
    @OrderColumn
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
class GroupB {
    .... id, .. omitted
    @ElementCollection
    @OrderColumn
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

These groups are contained within another entity in lists as well. I'm using @Transactional in my service, where I request the entities, and `Hibernate.initialize(method)` for loading children when needed (inside my service).

When I refactor into a base class, which the items can extend, like:

```
@MappedSuperClass
public class BaseItem {
    @Id
    @GenereratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ElementCollection
    @OrderColumn
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

When I run this I get an error `Failed to lazy initialize collection`. I can solve it by adding `fetch=EAGER` to my element collection.

Am I doing something wrong? I would expect no different behavior at all when using `@MappedSuperClass`

**UPDATE 1** A very crucial part, which I forgot to mention is than I'm using Hibernate Envers to audit my group

**UPDATE 2**: Code for my service:

```
@Service
@Transactional 
public class ProductService{
    private ProductRepository repository;

    public ProductService(ProductRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Product findOne(Integer id) {
        Product one = repository.findOne(id);
        Hibernate.initialize(one.getAGroups());
        Hibernate.initialize(one.getBGroups());

        return one;
    }
}
```

and for completeness, my Product entity:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Getter
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<GroupA> aGroups = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<GroupB> bGroups = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: The error you describe sounds like something that depends on your service. Can you post the service code that uses the mapped classes?

Comment: @Yserbius Thanks for your reply. I have updated my post.

Comment: Can you add the exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Your issues looks like it's in calling `one.getAGroups()` which kind of defeats the purpose of a lazy load when you load up all the items in the group in initialization. Either drop that code or use eager load.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure it really answers the question. The question is why the behavior changes when using MappedSuperClass. It works when the entity contains all the fields itself